# how to Iterate an Array List inside 2 bash loops

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, for-loop

I have 2 arrays in bash.
Array number 1 is the vlan subnet without the last octet.
Array number 2 is a list of octets i want to ignore, while scanning the subnet with Nmap.
lets assume every subnet has 254 pingable ip's (class c subnet)
I want the script to scan each subnet, and exclude ip's that ends with 1,2,3,252,253,254 which are Usually routers / firewalls / switches.
I manages to run 2 iterations, but failed on the if [[ $host == $host."${ignore[@]" ]] to identify the relevant ip (sunbet + ignore string)
Would really appreciate your help.

```
#!/bin/bash

# lets assume each subnet has 254 ips and all ignore ip's like 10.6.114.1 10.6.115.1 and 10.5.120.1
declare -a vlans=(
10.6.114
10.6.115
10.5.120
)

declare -a ignore=(
1
2
3
252
253
254
)

for vlan in "${vlans[@]}"; do

        nmap -sn "$vlan" | grep Nmap | awk "{print $5}" | sed -n '1!p' | sed -e "$d" | sort > /tmp/vlan_ips.txt
        readarray -t hosts < /tmp/vlan_ips.txt

        for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do

                check=$(echo "$host" | cut -d"." -f1-3)

                if [ $host == $check."${ignore[@]}" ]; then
                        echo 'skipping record'
                fi

        done
done
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Why do you think `$host == $host.$ignore` could match?

Comment: what do you mean by `failed on the last` ... error? wrong output? no output? consider updating the question to include sample contents of the `hosts[]` array for each of the 3 `vlans[]` entries

Comment: what do you mean 'failed'? failed how? error? wrong output? no output? update the question with the details; regardless, you've introduced a new syntax issue (please run code through the shellcheck.net link provided by Cyrus); Renaud's questoin still applies ... how do you expect `$host` to be equal to itself **plus** something appended to `$host`

Comment: I'm **assuming** you mean `$host == $vlan.$ignore[@]` but since `ignore` is an array you'll need a way to test against each entry in the `ignore` array (eg, a 3rd `for` loop); an alternative would be to parse `$host` to get the last tuple and test for said tuple being in the `ignore` array; 'course, this issue applies to each pass through your loops so I'm not sure how you've determined the first 2 passes 'work' ... ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```sh
for vlan in "${vlans[@]}"; do
  
  for ign in "${ignore[@]}"; do
    printf '%s.%s\n' "$vlan" "$ign"
  done >/tmp/ignore

  nmap -n -sn "$vlan.0/24" -oG - 2>/dev/null |
  grep -vwFf /tmp/ignore |
  awk '/Host:/{print $2}' |
  while read -r host; do
    echo "$host"
  done
done
```